# GridView and CheckBoxList with UpdatePanel in asp.net (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, updatepanel, checkboxlist

I have an CheckBoxList within UpdatePanel which has onselectedindex change event on this event i have to update my gridview by fetching data from database. Event perform well but GridView not showing updated data may be because of GridView not in updatepanel.

Actually my problem is data not updated in gridview after firing onselectedindexchanged of Checkboxlist, and i cannot put gridview inside the updatepanel(its mandatory for me).

onselectedindexchanged event working fine i am already checked it out. So how can i update my gridview data.

Here is my code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="MonthUpdatePanel" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:CheckBoxList ID="MonthCheckBoxList" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" 
         onselectedindexchanged="MonthCheckBoxList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
       Width="195px"  onclick="updateviewmore()" >
       <asp:ListItem Value="1">1 Month</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="2">2 Month</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="6">6 Month</asp:ListItem>
       <asp:ListItem Value="12">1 Year</asp:ListItem>
       </asp:CheckBoxList>
   </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>

<div>
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"  Width="100%"
     GridLines="None" onrowdatabound="GridView2_RowDataBound" 
     ShowHeader="False">
      <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <div class="pad5">

                 <asp:Label ID="BookImageName" Text='<% #"../BookImages/"+ Eval("BookImage") %>'           CssClass="BookImage" runat="server" Height="180px" Width="135px" />

            </div>

       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't do that. Not if the `GridView` is outside the `UpdatePanel`. Your options are:

1. Remove the `UpdatePanel` and use full postbacks
2. Add a `PostbackTrigger` to the `UpdatePanel` and specify the `CheckboxList` as triger element...this is similar to the above...it'll always cause a full postback
3. Put the `GridView` inside the `UpdatePanel` and everything will be done in an async postback
4. Move the `CheckboxList` outside of the `UpdatePanel`, then put the `GridView` inside the `UpdatePanel` and add an `AsyncPostbackTrigger` for the `CheckboxList` so the `UpdatePanel` gets update asynchronously when and item is checked

The bottom line is, if you want to re-bind the `GridView` asynchronously then you'll have to move it inside the `UpdatePanel` or else you'll have to go with full postback approach

#### A Hardcore Solution

You can still do everything manually with the help of the `jQuery` plugin, a `UserControl` and an http handler that you could create to serve the necessary html. That is, intercept the html requests from client-side, make an async request to the handler passing some parameters so that the handler knows how to tell the `UserControl` how to bind the `GridView`...of course, the `GridView` will be inside a `UserControl`

The handler can write the output of a `UserControl` to the response using [`Execute` method of the `HttpServerUtility` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb04e8f7(v=vs.110).aspx) instance which is available in the current `HttpContext`. For example...

```
public class YourHandler: IHttpHandler {
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext ctx){
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        ctx.Server.Execute("~/UserControl.ascx", output, false);
        ctx.Response.Write(writer);
    } 
}
```

This method effective works as if the `UserControl` was passing through all the ASP.NET pipeline cycles during a normal request and its context will be exactly the same context of the http handler...so, if you're using built-in asp.net membership features make sure to use a generic handler (.ashx) which plugs into the ASP.NET pipeline by itself with no further effort from your side